# Add Wine app to Cinnamon task bar

Tags: linux, cinnamon, wine, panel

I want to add cmd.exe (a wine app) to the cinammon task bar. If I right click on the app it not has this option and if I right click on the running app and "pin to Panel" the app is pinned but when I click it not work. This problem only occurs with wine apps.

Comment: Emulated software doesn't work that way.

Comment: With Xfce it works, why not in Cinammon?  I prefer Cinnamon over Xfce but I need it to works with wine apps and btw, Wine is not an emulator :-)

Comment: instead of adding a launcher to run `cmd.exe`, try adding one (or editing the existing one) to run `wine cmd.exe` (i.e. run `wine` with argument `cmd.exe`).  for other programs not in WINE's default path, you'll need to specify the full path.